# Scrapy Spider:relative link and absolute link

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

There is an example in Scrapy Documentation Release 1.0.3,in 7th row, *urljoin* method is used when the links is relative.when the links is absolute,what should i do?

example code:

```
import scrapy


class StackOverflowSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'stackoverflow'
    start_urls = ['http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes']

    def parse(self, response):
        for href in response.css('.question-summary h3 a::attr(href)'):
            full_url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
            yield scrapy.Request(full_url, callback=self.parse_question)

    def parse_question(self, response):
        yield {
            'title': response.css('h1 a::text').extract()[0],
            'votes': response.css('.question .vote-count-post::text').extract()[0],
            'body': response.css('.question .post-text').extract()[0],
            'tags': response.css('.question .post-tag::text').extract(),
            'link': response.url,
        }
```

Comment: You can only get the `href` value and store in `full_url` : `full_url = href.extract()`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to worry about, `urljoin()` handles both cases properly:

```
In [1]: response.urljoin("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/checking-a-checkbox-with-jquery")
Out[1]: 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/checking-a-checkbox-with-jquery'

In [2]: response.urljoin("/questions/426258/checking-a-checkbox-with-jquery")
Out[2]: 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/checking-a-checkbox-with-jquery'
```